# Ubuntu 20.04 C-Kermit 9.0.302

Tags: ssh, telnet

C-Kermit is, to this day, unavailable for apt installation for Ubuntu 20.04.

I got the tar from columbia.edu, tried to compile but failed.

Comment: How did it fail? We can't help you if you don't give us any hints!!

Comment: Also, C-kermit seems rather outdated. The page says:Version: 9.0.302, Released:  20 August 2011

Comment: ncurses was not detected from the original makefile and a POSIX dependency was unsuitably asked for in one of the source files. C-Kermit 9.0.302 is the last version from Columbia university. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kermit_(protocol)#History

Comment: "out of date" hardly covers it.  But some of us are still supporting legacy dial-up services.  It would be nice for us if ckermit stuck around ...

Comment: @Frobozz I use kermit to this date, ssh through it to more than one host service. It gives you the opportunity to transfer with kermit from the other side, while on the ssh session. I can remember a time when the internet was a university thing only, kermit was the only transfer protocol from the net.

Answer (score 3):

I had success compiling the source from the [C-Kermit “Daily” Source-Code Archive](http://www.kermitproject.org/ckdaily.html) on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: yes they have updated the source, no need for the patch

Comment: But I could not compile the cku 9.0.302 sourcecode

Answer (score 2):

As this is something I have a need for and until a formal release is out, I patched makefile and ckucmd.c and Kermit compiles normally.

first of all, you'll need to install libpam development->
sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev

C-Kermit can be obtained from:
http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ck90.html

and finally, a link to the two files changed:
https://mega.nz/file/DL4nnZhD#1-Wr-QnywqsjNFxMstz4L0b8cf3eBPv6vt9DycpGoUY

build with->
make linux

Hope this has helped those who use kermit for file transfer, through ssh or telnet.

Thanks.

Comment: I found that the Columbia download links for cku302.tar.gz were bad, but googling that filename came up with some useful alternatives.

Comment: @ChrisCombs here is the continued project http://www.kermitproject.org/ck90.html Actually, this doesn't need my patch anymore :)

Answer (score 2):

In the makefile, under the linux target, replace section:

```
HAVE_LIBCURSES=''; \
if test -f /usr/lib64/libncurses.so || \
   test -f /usr/lib/libncurses.a  || \
   test -f /usr/lib/libncurses.so; then \
  HAVE_LIBCURSES='-lncurses'; \
```

with section:

```
HAVE_LIBCURSES=''; \
if test -f /usr/lib64/libncurses.so || \
   test -f /usr/lib/libncurses.a  || \
   test -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so  || \
   test -f /usr/lib/libncurses.so; then \
  HAVE_LIBCURSES='-lncurses'; \
```

Since someone deemed it useful to change the old `/usr/lib`, `/usr/lib64` structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the C-Kermit author.  C-Kermit 10.0 is in Beta test, please look here:

```
https://kermitproject.org/ckupdates.html
```

The current makefile has a completely different way of dealing with curses.

Frank da Cruz
The Kermit Project
fdc@columbia.edu

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As for myself, I am using version 10.0, no problems detected so far.